# How can I connect to a AWS Windows Server instance via RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I set up a Windows 2012 free tier instance, got the Windows password from the *.pem file, and in the Instances view from the AWS console, got the IPv4 public IP.

On my Windows 10 laptop, started mstsc.exe, put the IPv4 public IP address in the computer field, clicked the Connect button, and got this error:

"Remote Desktop cannot connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons..."

I checked firewall and made sure nothing is getting blocked.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what's going on here -- does anyone know how to connect to a Windows server on AWS?

Thanks!